# What operating system could I load onto an Apple iMac G4

Tags: macos, operating-system

I just bought an old Apple iMac G4 for $10 at a yard sale and I'm trying to figure out what I could install on the unit to make it somewhat functional/useful.  For $10 I couldn't resist. Now if I can figure out something that I can actually install on it that would make it useful I will have gotten a great deal.

Any thoughts and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Wrong site for this question - try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install

- any Mac OS X up to 10.5
- any Linux distro for PowerPC (see e.g. [Penguin PPC](http://penguinppc.org/about-2/distributions/)